# Django Heroku hellodjango crash

Tags: django, deployment, heroku

i'm trying to upload a Django project to Heroku if i clone the hellodjango project i get this error:

[image]

Heroku code:

```
git clone git://github.com/heroku/python-django-sample.git
cd python-django-sample
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

Do i need to change something in settings.py?  I've tried with a node-js example and works great, but not django.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a few steps; but rather than type them out here - I would refer you to the [official documentation on running django on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) which has all these steps detailed.

The short summary is:

1. Install the [heroku toolchain](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/), so the `heroku` command works
2. Install [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)
3. Create a new virtual environment for your application
4. Install `django-toolbelt`, a Python virtual package that installs all the requirements for running django on heroku.
5. Develop your django application as normal
6. Once you are ready to deploy, create a [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). This tells heroku how to run your application.
7. Create a requirements file, which heroku will use to install any dependencies (including django itself) in your environment. You can do this by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` (note, it should be called `requirements.txt`).
8. Since you cannot write to the local hard disk in heroku (and other PaaS environments), you need to use a database. Heroku provides a postgres database for development use. To set it up with django you need to modify your settings file. The [`dj-database-url`](https://crate.io/packages/dj-database-url/) utility does this for you. Simply set `DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()` in your `settings.py`
9. Create a [`wsgi.py`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#wsgi-py) that heroku will use to run your application.
10. Create a git repository; add your files, create an initial commit.
11. Finally set it up with heroku by running `heroku create` (to create a new application in heroku, and to add a remote to your git repository) and then run `git push heroku master` to send your files across.
12. Once your files are on heroku, you need to launch the application there. Do that with `heroku ps:scale web=1` (this starts one web worker), and then browse the application with `heroku open`.

Comment: Yes i also try this before and when i check the state of the dyno i got:

 === web (1X): `gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi`
web.1: crashed 2013/08/13 01:52:05 (~ 28s ago)


I use this at the bottom of settings.py:     

import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the project locally (python manage.py runserver)? I had the same issue on Heroku, then I tried to run the application on my local webserver and I got error messages there. As soon as I got rid of them and updated my requirements.txt, Heroku was able to execute the application.